# Can I travel to the UK on different dates from those on my entry clearance?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I have a "Standard Visitor Entry Clearance" for the UK and will be traveling there from Saudi Arabia.

Is it necessary to travel on the same date I provided on my application?

Will the Immigration Officer check?  Will it make problems if I travel on a different date?

Comment: Is your entry date between the Valid From and Valid Until dates on the visa?  Is the date you will arrive materially different?  Was your application primarily based on attending an event (say a wedding or conference) which was on a fixed date, meaning that your reason for entry has materially changed?

Comment: No there is no such events or occasions I mentioned.. Its just em going to travel on 20 of this month what I mentioned was 15.. So is thatgoing to b ok right?

Comment: I don't anticipate you having any problem.  As long as your answers to any questions you are asked by the immigration officer match up with your application then you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A UK entry clearance gives you 'formal' permission to arrive/depart any time between its start and end dates.

The form asked for your travel dates so that they can try to align the visa's start date so that your time in the UK is maximized.  Once the entry clearance has been issued, it's ok to change your actual travel date.

You can arrive at 12:01 AM on the start date of your visa or any time after that over the visa's life time.  Trying to arrive earlier than the start date is not allowed.

And remember, you will still have a landing interview, and if your actual dates somehow contradict the premise of your visit, the IO may become worried.  Also remember that you signed an agreement to advise the British issuing post of any significant changes in your circumstances.  It's down to you to determine if your change of plans is derived from a reportable event.

Comment: Does 5 days of change gonna matter? And in the form i mentioned my stay in uk for 20 days can i change it for 25 days?

Comment: That's fine.  As long as the change is not reportable and your premise is still intact there's nothing to worry about.  It's a good question you asked and I might edit it later to be more generic so as to help others.  Hope that's ok...